# HttpClient и многопоточность

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток.

Я думаю, многие из вас уже сталкивались с проблемой утечки памяти при "неправильной" работе с классом `HttpClient` => Подвисают сокеты/соединения при услиленной инициализации инстанса (в многопоточном приложении). Кто-то советует инициализировать единожды, кто-то использовать `HttpClientFactory`.

**Не хотелось бы** тянуть доп. пакеты для использования `HttpClientFactory` (условие : .net Framework)

Я так и не смог сформировать четкое понимание как решить проблему в условиях:

- многопоточности
- на .net Framework 4
- при постоянной замене проксей

пример неправильного кода:

```
private static async Task<string> Request(string url)
{
     using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
     using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
     {
          // handler => set cookies, proxy
          return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
     }
}
```

Посоветуйте потокобезопасное решение.

Comment: Заведите один инстанс, и пересоздавайте в случае, если надо перетянуть изменения DNS.

Comment: По каком принципу прокси выбираются?

Comment: @Vasek, особых правил нет. есть пул доступных + статистика использования

Comment: @PashaPash, а как поведет себя такой код, если "одновременно" два потока попытаются создать запросы с разными проксями ?

Comment: То есть все запросы лезут через один прокси, а потом прокси меняется и все начинают лезть через новый?

Comment: Авторизация на проксях требуется?

Comment: @Vasek, не совсем так. для каждого запроса - свой прокси, пока один используется он не может быть выдан другому потоку

Comment: @morphey83 С синглтоном - да, если вы поменяете прокси у общего handler - его применит ко всем потокам. Сделайте пул для HttpClient по проксям (хотя бы на concurrent dictionary).

Comment: @morphey83 если прокси для потока и управление потоками ручное - положите HttpClient в ThreadStatic.